# dump question on class access in java

Tags: java

I'm writing wrapper for java library. Suppose ClassA and ClassB (in default package). In ClassA we have:

```
ClassB.DoSomething();
```

javac throws an error:

```
ClassA.java:...: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable ClassB
```

where the problem is?

thank you in advance!!!

Comment: have you imported ClassB package?

Comment: are u sure u mean `class` not object?

Comment: They should ban default packages in Java!

Comment: ClassB is "public class ClassB". It's in default package, so as ClassA. I suppose I don't need to import it

Comment: >>>They should ban default packages in Java!>>> so if I put both packages in some package and write "package somepackage" in the top that should help?

Comment: is `DoSomething()` (BTW this is not compliant with the Java naming convention) a static public method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends how you want to access your method. For example, you can access it statically with something like

```
class ClassA {
    //...
    public void someMethod() {
        ClassB.doSomething();
    }
    //...
}

class ClassB {
    static public void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Or requiring an instance of `ClassB`

```
class ClassA {
    //...
    public void someMethod() {
        ClassB b = new ClassB();
        b.doSomething();
    }
    //...
}

class ClassB {
    public void doSomething() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Your question is vague as it is, so I'll stop here.

**Note** : remember that Java is case sensitive, meaning that `ClassB` != `classB`, etc.

Comment: I think we'd be seeing  different error if it was static at fault. Something like "non-static method doSomething() cannot be referenced from a static context"

Comment: @Gnat, at this time, everything is pure speculation :)

Answer (score 1):

Is the current directory on the classpath? It should be but if the setup isn't right then javac might get confused.

If ClassA and ClassB really are both in the default package, try compiling with `javac -cp . ClassA.java` and see if that works.